How do I adjust polkit rules to allow shutting down and rebooting from lock screen?(Super+L) Fedora Workstation
I don't want to have to log in just to power off my computer. It even disables the power button & Ctrl+Alt+Del so I cant use that either. I have autosave set up on everything so it doesnt save me from data loss either.
How to shut down Fedora without logging in
This possible duplicate issue does not have a solution.
